# Charset encoding toString to getbyte

Tags: java, sockets, character-encoding, tostring

the conversion string to byte and back are different. I use to encypt/decrypt des and when i recive a string by Server, the server make toString(),i make myString.getByte for decrypt. decrypt not working because Input length must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher... anyone can help me. thank you.
Server:

```
String keySession=DesKeySession.toString();
    String Message=keySessione+"1.1.1.1";
       byte [] text=(Message).getBytes();

           // Encrypt the text
        byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
        String StringtextEncrypted = textEncrypted.toString();
        OutLista.InsertTail(StringtextEncrypted);
//list to send client with all information
outToClient.writeObject(OutLista);
```

Client:

```
        String mesage=listaFromServer.DeleteTail();


        byte [] messaggioKab=(message).getBytes();          

        // Initialize the same cipher for decryption
           desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey); 


        // Decrypt the text
           byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(messaggioKab);//error
```

Comment: Edit your question to include your code which converts Strings to and from bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You are not converting a byte array to a String correctly.  You must use `new String`, not toString().
2. In C, you can use a string to hold bytes.  In Java, you cannot, because not every byte will be a valid representation of a character.

Both problems are due to this line:

```
String StringtextEncrypted = textEncrypted.toString();
```

In Java, all primitive arrays directly extend java.lang.Object.  Such arrays *do not* define a toString method, which means every primitive array inherits [the toString method of Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--), which for a byte array usually produces something like "[B@19de8a6f89".

For this reason, you cannot convert a byte array to a String using toString().  You must create a String directly:

```
String stringtextEncrypted = new String(textEncrypted);
```

However, this is *not safe* unless you know your bytes actually represent characters encoded with a [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).  Your bytes are not encoded in a charset—they are the result of an encryption operation.  It is never safe to store arbitrary bytes in a String as one might do in C, because the bytes may contain invalid sequences according to the charset used to decode them, and such invalid sequences will be automatically replaced with a designated "invalid sequence" character like `?` or `�` in the new String.

(The actual charset used is the platform's default charset, since you didn't specify one explicitly; that is another issue with your code, since the client and server may not have the same default charset, but the above problems need to be corrected first.)

Simply put, you cannot safely use a String to hold your encrypted bytes.  However, since `byte[]` is a subclass of Object, you can always put the encrypted byte array itself in your list.  All primitive arrays are serializable.

By the way, the convention in Java is for all variable names and method names to start with a lowercase letter (except static final variables, which are usually constants).  You should use names like `message`, `insertTail` and `deleteTail`.

Comment: i think to use encoding base64..